# IF ELSE - Capture if 0 rows returned

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Please see mock query below, IF 1 is not valid I want '1 does not exist' message to return but if 1 is a valid value and 0 rows can be returned, say for a set day, I want another error message, e.g. '2', is this possible?

```
DECLARE @1 
DECLARE @Date

SET @1 
SET @Date

IF @1 IN SELECT A FROM Table

SELECT

-- *Run Query here* - Would like if 0 rows a message to also appear here. 

ELSE 

'1 does not exist'
```

Comment: You seems to be missing several things, like variables naming rules and data types

Comment: What database are you using? SQL Server, MySQL, etc.

Comment: Please have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Maybe you can add more information to your question

Comment: I re-tagged the question with `tsql` and `sql-server` based on the syntax show. If that is not what you use, then please tag with the correct DBMS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understood your question correctly, you want logic like this:

```
declare @valueToFind nvarchar(10) = 'something'
, @date DateTime = '2018-01-01'

if exists (select top 1 1 from TablelistingValidValues where AValue = @value)
begin
    if exists (select top 1 1 from TableWithActualData where AValue = @value and ADate = @date)
    begin 
        select * 
        from TableWithActualData 
        where AValue = @value 
        and ADate = @date
    end
    else
    begin
        throw 50001, 'The record does not exist on the given date.', 1  
    end
end
else
begin 
    throw 50000, 'The record does not exist / AValue is invalid.', 1  
end
```

i.e.

- You have a variable holding some value.
- You have another variable holding a date.
- If that value appears in a certain lookup table it's considered valid.
- If the value is invalid (doesn't appear in the lookup table) we throw an error.
- If the value does appear you want to select all records with that value on the given date.
- If there are records for that value/date combo, you want to return them
- If there are no matching records, you want to throw a different error.

NB: 50000/50001 are error numbers that you can define; i.e. so each place you throw an error you can have a unique number for it.  Generally I rely more on the message to give informative information; but the number can be helpful too.

Answer (score 0):

For T-SQL:

```
DECLARE @1 int; // declare types
DECLARE @Date DATE;
SET @1 = 0; // set value
SET @Date = '2018-09-13';
IF @1 IN (SELECT A FROM table)
SELECT
-- *Run Query here* - Would like if 0 rows a message to also appear here. 
ELSE     
select '1 does not exist';
```